# SPSS: How to decompose interactions in repeated measures ANCOVA?

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, ancova, continuous-data

I conducted a study with three categorical within-factors and one continuous personality variable:

topic (1,2) x gain loss framing (1,2) x achievement security framing (1,2) x personality

I know how to use the MMATRIX command in SPSS to decompose interactions between my within-factors, but I don't know how to handle interactions with the continuous covariate. At one point I get a three-way interaction of topic x achievement security framing x personality, for  example. I'd like to know if there is a two-way interaction of framing x personality for topic 1, but how do I test for that?

If it was just a two-way interaction I could use the COMPARE command, since that one can be used together with a WITH covariate command. But since it is a three-way interaction I'm not sure what to do. You can't use the WITH command together with MMATRIX, right?

I'd be super grateful for any piece of advice.
Thanks for your help!